# MATLAB: understanding the role of surf

Tags: matlab, gaussian, normal-distribution

I need some help understanding the role of the [surf](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html) function in this MATLAB sample code. The code comes from some [online documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/multivariate-normal-distribution.html) on the Multivariate Normal(Gaussian) Distribution.

**Sample Code:**

```
mu = [0 0];
Sigma = [.25 .3; .3 1];
x1 = -3:.2:3; x2 = -3:.2:3;
[X1,X2] = meshgrid(x1,x2);
F = mvnpdf([X1(:) X2(:)],mu,Sigma);
F = reshape(F,length(x2),length(x1));
surf(x1,x2,F);
caxis([min(F(:))-.5*range(F(:)),max(F(:))]);
axis([-3 3 -3 3 0 .4])
xlabel('x1'); ylabel('x2'); zlabel('Probability Density');
```

Here, they are creating a Gaussian filter, `F`.

I'm not sure what this `surf` is illustrating mathematically, in context of the multivariate distribution. Is this just showing what the filter, `F`, looks like?

Comment: `surf` is the command to plot surfaces defined by (x,y,z)-coordinates. In this sample code it plots the probability density function of the multi-variate normal distribution, i.e. the values `F` as a function of `X1` and `X2`, computed by `mvnpdf`. To me a Gaussian filter is something else, but maybe that is what you would call it ...

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @souty. "the values F as a function of X1 and X2" - still unsure of what this means mathematically. Is this as if I am applying the filter to X1 and X2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, `surf` here is just showing the shape of the filter.**

Running your code gives me [this plot (which I also rotated to view from above):](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMR4n.png)

You can see that the normal Gaussian distribution has different sigmas along the two dimensions (and is rotated), which is determined by `Sigma`. The `surf` function is showing the shape of the filter, `F`. In other words, the weight of the filter at different x,y locations.

To plot the height/value of the filter at different locations, it needs a bunch of x,y pairs, which it gets from the X1 and X2 mesh. It's not running the filter across the mesh.

A filter in MATLAB is usually just a matrix, which can be convolved with another data matrix (such as an image) to apply the filter to the data.

For 2D convolutions, use `conv2`.